# Terminal does not start; how to fix it?

Tags: gnome-terminal

Clicking on terminal icon, not opening and on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> also same problem occurs

Answer (score 0):

In some cases when you upgrade python3.5 to python3.6 problems occurs
For that open a *virtual terminal*
by pressing  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>
then enter login details as ***username*** and ***password***

then run two commands

```
sudo rm /usr/bin/python3
sudo ln -s python3.5 /usr/bin/python3
```

then close the session with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>D</kbd> and exit the virtual terminal by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd>